# Parse.com current user if statement

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm using Parse as a mobile back end to my application. I have added 2 boolean column to my 'User' data table (User class) 'coach' and 'club' basically stating are they a coach or a club. During login need to perform if statements based on the boolean value of these variables.  My code currently is as follows:

```
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:_usernameField.text password:_passwordField.text
                                block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                    if (user) {

                                        if(user.coach = @YES){
                                            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"coach"]; //sets yes for coach value

                                        }

                                        if(user.club = @YES){
                                          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"club"]; //sets yes for club
                                        }

                                        UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"AthleteLoggedIn" bundle:nil];
                                        UISplitViewController *new = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
                                        self.view.window.rootViewController = new;

                                    } else {
                                        NSString *errorString = [error userInfo][@"error"];
                                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Oops" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                                        [alert show];
                                    }
                                }];
```

Comment: `if(user.coach = @YES)` should be `if(user.coach == @YES)`. same for `user.club`. in your statement, you assigned `@YES` to the variable and then evaluated the value of the variable (which is of course `@YES`)

Comment: To avoid this next time you should get into the habit of putting constant on the left side of the comparison if(@YES == user.coach). if(@YES = user.couch) would have thrown a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. The first being that you're using the assignment operator `=`, and the second is that you're using dot notation for a Parse object.

What you had:

```
if(user.coach = @YES){ /* ... */ }
if(user.club = @YES){ /* ... */ }
```

The correct implementation:

```
if([user objectForKey:@"coach"] == @YES){ /* ... */ }
if([user objectForKey:@"club"] == @YES){ /* ... */ }
```

Which can be reduced to:

```
if([user objectForKey:@"coach"]){ /* ... */ }
if([user objectForKey:@"club"]){ /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Thank you, as you probably guessed I'm quite new to Xcode, although i really sure should have got the the double =. Thank you very much though and he reduction is very helpful for my understanding. Reading though Parse's documentation I was unsure where they declared if statements on variables. This very much clears it up. Thanks again to everyone!